Keybinding Service Not Logging Keys
I'm hoping to issue the keyboard command to split selection into multiple lines.
It's my understanding that the default keyboard shortcut is cmd + shift + l as per the keybindings view. However, when I "Record keys", this combination yields cmd + shift only.
I receive this result when I launch the "Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting" upon pressing cmd + shift + p
2024-04-09 11:23:59.173 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-04-09 11:23:59.174 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-04-09 11:23:59.174 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 91, key: Meta
2024-04-09 11:23:59.174 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [meta], code: MetaLeft, keyCode: 57 ('Meta')
2024-04-09 11:23:59.175 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-04-09 11:24:00.581 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Soft dispatching keyboard event
2024-04-09 11:24:00.581 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched
2024-04-09 11:24:00.581 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [shift,meta], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
2024-04-09 11:24:00.582 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [shift,meta], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
2024-04-09 11:24:00.582 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2024-04-09 11:24:04.761 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier meta due to it being pressed together with other keys.

However, when launching Karabiner Event Viewer, it's correctly logging the keys.
I'm using a 2019 Macbook Pro running Sonoma 14.4.1.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues
